# Get coordinates from getJSON when a users clicks on a polygon

Tags: jquery, json, coordinates, getjson, geojson

I would like to be able to get the coordinates from my json file to make my polygon(s) editable when a user clicks a polygon. There can be an unlimited number of polygons displayed on my Google map.

To load my polygon I use the following

```
$.getJSON('PATH TO FILE', function (data) {
var features = map.data.addGeoJson(data);
 });
```

I then add a click map listener so when the user clicks on the polygon the information in the json file is shown in div tags like so:

```
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
var WTGlobal = "rows='4' style='text-align:left; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:9px; width:96%'";
var RRGlobal = "type='text' size='3' maxlength='4' style='text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:9px' autocomplete='off'";
var PPGlobal = "type='text' size='3' maxlength='3' style='text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:9px' autocomplete='off'";
var TTGlobal = "type='text' size='3' maxlength='4' style='text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:9px' autocomplete='off'";
var MMGlobal = "type='text' size='3' maxlength='4' style='text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:9px' autocomplete='off'";

 document.getElementById('REGION').textContent = event.feature.getProperty('Region');
 document.getElementById('ISSUED').textContent = event.feature.getProperty('Issued');
 document.getElementById('VALIDT').textContent = event.feature.getProperty('Valid');
```

etc.......

At this point is where I need help.
When the user clicks on the polygon I would like to be able to retrieve the coordinates from my json file so the coordinates can be included in a new function to be able to make the polygon editable again.

This is what I have tried to retrieve the coordinates

```
var coords = event.feature.getGeometry('coordinates');
alert(coords);
```

This just returns object back in my alert box.

The new function where I need to feed my coordinates to is below:

```
function EditPolgons(){
 alert("Do you want to Edit polygon?");
  nowEditingShape = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: coords,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
editable: true
});
nowEditingShape.setMap(map);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this one out. In my json I added the lat, lng as a string then I could retrive them to make a copy of the polygon which was clicked. The copy could then be editable.

```
map.data.addListener('dblclick', function(event) {
alert("Testing Edit Polygon");
//LOAD GeoJSON======================
$.getJSON('PATH TO URL', function (data) {
var features = map.data.addGeoJson(data);
});
var Id        =  event.feature.getProperty('Region');
var CoordsLat =  event.feature.getProperty('Lat');
var CoordsLng =  event.feature.getProperty('Lng');
var Lat  = new Array();
    var Lat  = CoordsLat.split(',');
    var Lng  = new Array();
    var Lng  = CoordsLng.split(',');
    var Paths =[];

    for (var i = 0, length = Lat.length; i < length; i++) { 
    Paths.push( new google.maps.LatLng(Lat[i],Lng[i]));
    }
    //CONSTRUCTION EDITABLE POLYGON
     EditablePolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
     editable: true,
     paths: Paths,
     strokeColor: '#FF0000',
     strokeOpacity: 0.8,
     strokeWeight: 3,
     fillColor: '#FF0000',
     fillOpacity: 0.35
     });
```

This now mean that if any users dblclicks on a number number of polygons they can make then editable and redraw the shape to suit.